# display table record got multiple?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap-3

can someone help my problem in php??
why i got multiple record when im displaying table record using join 4 table or more?? and in the table it got 2 record but in display (on the web) it become 6 record?? why??? is the script im using is wrong or what???
here the script :

```
<div class="modal-body row">
    <?php
        //$id = $_GET['nip'];
        $qry="
            select 
                tb_dosen.nip, tb_dosen.nidn_nidk, tb_dosen.nama, tb_dosen.jenis_kelamin, tb_dosen.alamat, tb_dosen.telepon, tb_dosen.agama, tb_dosen.pendidikan_terakhir, tb_dosen.jabatan, tb_dosen.email, tb_dosen.foto,
                tb_bimbingan.no_bimbingan, tb_bimbingan.nip, tb_bimbingan.tahun_bimbingan, tb_bimbingan.nama_mahasiswa,tb_bimbingan.judul,
                tb_pendidikan.no_pendidikan, tb_pendidikan.nip, tb_pendidikan.tahun_lulus, tb_pendidikan.jenjang, tb_pendidikan.gelar,  tb_pendidikan.nama_universitas,  tb_pendidikan.bidang_ilmu,  tb_pendidikan.no_ijasah,
                tb_buku.no_buku, tb_buku.nip, tb_buku.penulis, tb_buku.judul_buku, tb_buku.penerbit_buku, tb_buku.tahun_terbit,
                tb_jabatan_ak.no_jabatan, tb_jabatan_ak.nip, tb_jabatan_ak.tahun_diangkat, tb_jabatan_ak.posisi, tb_jabatan_ak.no_sk,
                tb_jafung.no_jafung, tb_jafung.nip, tb_jafung.tahun_jafung, tb_jafung.jafung, tb_jafung.sk_jafung, tb_jafung.sk_sertifikasi,
                tb_penelitian.no_penelitian, tb_penelitian.nip, tb_penelitian.tahun_penelitian, tb_penelitian.judul_penelitian, tb_penelitian.tempat_publikasi,
                tb_pengajaran.no_pengajaran, tb_pengajaran.nip, tb_pengajaran.tahun_akademik, tb_pengajaran.semester, tb_pengajaran.mata_kuliah, tb_pengajaran.sk_mengajar,
                tb_penghargaan.no_penghargaan, tb_penghargaan.nip, tb_penghargaan.tanggal_penghargaan, tb_penghargaan.jenis_penghargaan, tb_penghargaan.pemberi,
                tb_pkm.no_pkm, tb_pkm.nip, tb_pkm.tahun_pkm, tb_pkm.judul_pkm, tb_pkm.tempat_pkm, tb_pkm.publikasi_pkm,
                tb_seminar.no_seminar, tb_seminar.nip, tb_seminar.judul_seminar, tb_seminar.sebagai, tb_seminar.jenis_seminar, tb_seminar.kota, tb_seminar.tanggal_seminar
            from tb_dosen
                INNER JOIN tb_bimbingan ON tb_bimbingan.nip = tb_dosen.nip
                INNER JOIN tb_pendidikan ON tb_pendidikan.nip = tb_dosen.nip
                INNER JOIN tb_buku ON tb_buku.nip = tb_dosen.nip
                INNER JOIN tb_jabatan_ak ON tb_jabatan_ak.nip = tb_dosen.nip
                INNER JOIN tb_jafung ON tb_jafung.nip = tb_dosen.nip
                INNER JOIN tb_penelitian ON tb_penelitian.nip = tb_dosen.nip
                INNER JOIN tb_pengajaran ON tb_pengajaran.nip = tb_dosen.nip
                INNER JOIN tb_penghargaan ON tb_penghargaan.nip = tb_dosen.nip
                INNER JOIN tb_pkm ON tb_pkm.nip = tb_dosen.nip
                INNER JOIN tb_seminar ON tb_seminar.nip = tb_dosen.nip
            where tb_dosen.nip = '$_GET[nip]'
        ";
        $hasil=mysql_query($qry) or die ("".mysql_error());
        $row = mysql_num_rows($hasil) or die ("".mysql_error());
        $data=mysql_fetch_array($hasil) or die ("".mysql_error());
    ?><table class="table table-condensed">
                            <tr>
                                <th>No.</th>
                                <th>Tahun Lulus</th>
                                <th>Jenjang</th>
                                <th>Gelar</th>
                                <th>Nama Universitas</th>
                                <th>Bidang Ilmu</th>
                                <th>No. Ijazah</th>
                            </tr>
                            <?php 
                            while ($k=mysql_fetch_array($hasil)) 
                            {
                                $a=$k['no_pendidikan'];
                                $b=$k['tahun_lulus'];
                                $c=$k['jenjang'];
                                $d=$k['gelar'];
                                $e=$k['nama_universitas'];
                                $f=$k['bidang_ilmu'];
                                $g=$k['no_ijasah']; 
                            ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $a ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $b ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $c ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $d ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $e ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $f ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo $g ?></td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </table>
```

sorry if  im using indonesia language, for the table
and sorry for my bad english#

## here for full ver. http://pastebin.com/qgr4rHJC

for pic # goo.gl/6mT0gi

Comment: Use Group by on necessary columns.

Comment: And don't use $_GET directly for creating sql statements! This is an open door for sql injection.

Comment: @RuchishParikh do you mean use "form group" bootstrap?

Comment: @JoachimSchirrmacher : umm...sorry...don't use $_get ?? im using $_get to get data from table (something like showing each user that has data for that user only).if im not use $_get...then what i must use??? cause im still new to php #sorry_my_english

Comment: have you run the query in phpmyadmin does it return data two times there too?

Comment: You may use $_GET, but you shouldn't use it directly to concatenate a sql query. Instead, escape data like described in http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: @AhmedKhan: yes, it same?... then the query wrong?? 
here pic : http://imgur.com/ASjE4e0

Comment: @JoachimSchirrmacher: ok thank's gonna study it...then....about my question??? what is wrong ?? #sorry the query or what??

Comment: Yup it's the problem with your query.

Comment: @AhmedKhan can you help me with the query?? im still new to php, and already try using where but still same result...please help me  like example query statement for 11 table ..

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be something wrong with your sql statement.

With every join, you create kind of multiplied result set. So, if you have 3 records in your base table and two in a joined table, you get 6 rows in your result. The join condition normally reduces this count by removing those rows, which do not match it.

Check your 'nip' value in every database table, if there is more that one row containing the same value, then there is the source of your doubled entries.

Answer (score 0):

@Joachim Schirrmacher

at database table, let say,
tb_dosen is tb_table1, tb_pendidikan is tb_table2 and tb_buku is tb_table3, till tb_table10, cause these 10 table will relation to tb_table1 (like relation 1 to many).

im looking at database every table have 2 record (for now), first for "nip1" (let say nip is like number that must have 'uique' fiture or primary) second for "nip2".

now at tb_table2 there 4 record (just adding 1 now) for these 4 record have a field named "nip" (foreign key for relation), each "nip" in tb_tbale2 have 2 record, ,and the other table too will become like the tb_table2....so when im click these "nip1" (the primary one) the other *nip* on the other table (tb_table3 till 10) will showing only the data that im click, but when im using that query, the record it become multiple, why???